# How to move an element automatically when I drag/resize another element?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, jquery-ui-draggable

How to move an element automatically when I drag/resize another element ?

I would like to move `div.duree` and when it is close to another `div.duree`. 
At the moment, I can drag the elements independently of each other but they overlap. And I don't want to overlay, I want that moves if they ever should overlap.

Is there a way to do that ?

[image]

index.html

```
  <div class="parent">
    <div class="duree" draggable resizable></div> 
    <div class="duree" draggable resizable></div> 
  </div>
```

directive.js

```
angular.directive('resizable', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    controller: function resizableCtrl($scope, $element){  
      $element.resizable({
         containment: "parent",
         grid: 25
      });
    }  
  }
});

angular.directive('draggable', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    controller: function draggableCtrl($scope, $element){  
      $element.draggable({
        containment: "parent", 
        axis: "x", 
        grid: [ 25, 0 ] 
      });
    }  
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using drag-n-drop, there are a few key points.

1. The drag operation is a pending operation that can be cancelled.
2. To *move* an element out of the way, you need to update the DOM (probably be adding new elements).

I'm assuming you want the UX to show the user a *live* view of what everything would look like if you dropped the element "right now".

To detect the overlay, I recommend making all relevant elements *droppable*. When you detect the *dragenter* or *dragover*, update the DOM however you need to move the overlaid element. For example, you could add a new div with a dotted outline to denote the pending nature if you "dropped right there".

If the user cancels the drag, you need to undo the temporary changes to the DOM.